# Pagination using Spring JPA PagingAndSortingRepository and thymeleaf

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, thymeleaf

I'm trying to create a data table with all selected data, paging (previous, next) and sorting then present in in a thymeleaf template. I'm trying to use the PagingAndSortingRepository of Spring. Can someone point me to the right direction? I'm new to Spring.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have just finished writing this tutorial, maybe it will help you.

[Spring Data JPA Pagination - W3Stacks](https://w3stacks.com/spring-data/spring-data-jpa-pagination)

Comment: Thanks I appreciate the help, I'll try to get as much from this.